# OData or WCF Soap

Tags: soap, odata

My company needs to share data with outside organizations as well as extract data from outside clients. Our application team is currently debating whether to implement OData service to share & extract data or build a soap based web service.
could anyone please let me know what should be the right approach towards sharing data with outside clients as well as extract their data into our databases.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, an OData service is better than a soap based webservice, the reason is that:

1. Soap based web service are much heavy, and there are many standards about it such as WS-*. Nowadays, many people are using Restful web services especially developing new ones.
2. OData is a special Restful web service. Here is the official word: "OData is a standardized protocol for creating and consuming data APIs. OData builds on core protocols like HTTP and commonly accepted methodologies like REST. The result is a uniform way to expose full-featured data APIs."

You can play with it here http://services.odata.org/v4/OData/OData.svc/ and here are some sample code about it: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/